# How to make this border bottom curve on every section?

Tags: html, css

I am setting up a new website layout, But I don't have no knowledge how to make this border bottom curve on every section, please look at this image, can anyone provide me some idea about it?

I had tried to crop all the background image out from each section, but it doesn't fit to all resolutions.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/DHC0C.png

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it simply using below css...

```css
.container {
  display: block;
  margin: auto;
  width: 400px;
  height: 300px;
  background-color: #AAA;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-top-left-radius: 100% 10%;
  border-bottom-right-radius: 100% 10%;
  box-shadow: 0px 5px 15px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7) inset, 0px -5px 15px -8px rgba(0,0,0,0.7) inset;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
```

Comment: appreaciated for your fast reply sir, so much appreciated, i try to apply your code in my website and have a look, once again so much apprecaited, will let you know the result

Comment: hi sir, this is end up what it look like, i had tried similar like this to make the border radius curve, but this also the same result end up i got, any others solutions ? https://imgur.com/a/lxW1YO9

Comment: @NickLim What's wrong in it, I couldn't understand. Can you please explain?

Comment: my apologise if i cannot explain well,  you see the background from second section cannot actually cover the first section 
this is what i looking for - https://imgur.com/a/owJvak7
can you see the different? , i really apprecited your reply, also my apologise i cannot do it well

Comment: Which is the first section and section section? The front one or back one